# Tridion 2011 SP1 GA - Pages Successfully published, but queue is stuck in "Waiting for Deployment"

Tags: tridion

In Tridion 2011 SP1 GA, I constantly am getting this strange error at random times.

Publish a page, page is successfully written to the file system, but in the publishing queue it would be stuck in "Waiting for Deployment"

One day it would be successful and the next it would be stuck.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Constant or Random? Which is it?

Comment: I guess "random" was the wrong term. After a mass publishing phase and if transaction are stuck in the bin\transaction folder, the transport stop polling the deployer, which cause this problem. It's all starting to make much more sense now =)

Comment: Hi Robert, I just noticed you haven’t yet committed to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Could we borrow 5 seconds of your time and ask you to press the commit button, if you have a moment?

Answer (score 5):

This could be happening because your transport service has stopped polling the deployer because  the polling intervals/max poll time which are configured in the the Transport Service configuration file reach their limits. Assuming that is the case, the Deployer has continued to deploy files, but the Transport Service has given up checking. However, I would expect to see the status eventually report failed in the Publishing Queue.

It is not clear if you are using GA or SP1 of SDL Tridion 2011. There are a number of hot fixes which will help solve these issues for GA and HR1, all of which are bundled into SP1. Specifically these solve some issues relating to returning responses to the Transport Service after some sort of (non-catastrophic) failure in the Deployer after it gets a large queue of items or a a particularly large transaction to deal with. I strongly suggest you install the latest patches that before trying to adjust the behaviors through configuration.

If you have already applied all the patches, please double check that you have applied them correctly (copied all the new jars etc) to the CD side (Deployer and Broker etc) as well as the CM side.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chris! Your answer guided me in the right direction. Earlier, we did some massive publishing jobs and many items were stuck in the bin\transaction folder on the publisher server. Clearing the old transaction and restarting the transport/publisher service fixed the issue.